# How to Find all emoji from a PySpark Dataframe Column?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I have a column in a spark data frame which has several messages. Here is a sample:

```
message = [
  (1, "Sempre com @mariahcarey fazendo aquele aquecimento na voz antes dos shows. Quem lembra dessa? ❤️"),
  (2, "Happy Easter from the real bunny "),
  (3, "Anakku aku udah diajak nonton malam mingguan kemarin  tua Haduhhh bener2 deh @gadiiing @raffinagita1717")
]

rdd1 = sc.parallelize(message)
df=sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd1,['id', 'message'])
```

I need to find all the emojies in the messages. Using the following code it is possible to find the first match:

```
import emoji
import re

emojis_list = map(lambda x: ''.join(x.split()), emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI.keys())
escape_list = '|'.join(re.escape(p) for p in emojis_list)
df.withColumn("emoji_in_post", fn.regexp_extract("message", escape_list, 0))
```

But I need all of them. So I tried to create a UDF using vanila python.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType
import pyspark.sql.functions as fn

def find_all_emo(plain_text):
  emo_list = re.findall(escape_list, plain_text)
  return emo_list

search_all_emojis = fn.udf(lambda y: find_all_emo(y), ArrayType(StringType()))
```

But when applying that function to dataframe I am getting error.

```
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

If some one know the problem or has any better solution. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How are you applying the udf, could you add that code as well?

Answer (score 0):

So I found the problem. There is few rows when the value of message is null. So I had to extend the find all function.

```
def find_all_emo(plain_text):
  if plain_text is None:
    return None
  emo_list = regex.findall(plain_text)
  return emo_list

search_all_emojis = fn.udf(lambda y: find_all_emo(y), ArrayType(StringType()))

test = df.withColumn("emoji_in_post", search_all_emojis(fn.col("message")))
```

Now the output result is empty array or array with some emoji.